# Realtime Database Change Capture in Java Application

Tags: java, database, caching, jooq, change-data-capture

I've read the following article about cache synchronization and database.
Here the author uses JOOQ for cache synchronization.

https://vladmihalcea.com/cache-synchronization-jooq-postgresql-functions/

After reading the article I found that to know the database changes, we need to call the API manually.
Is there any pattern to get real-time notifications of the database changes to the Java application like web socket push?

Answer (score 0):

The solution in the article is meant to be called every N seconds to synchronize the cache.

The Web Sockets push is more useful for the UI than for backend services. If you want to make this synchronously, you could use PostgreSQL [NOTIFY](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-notify.html).

Comment: Hello Vlad, forgive me for bothering you directly: would you be able to help with this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76666162/cache-them-all-with-hibernate ? So far nobody was able to provide any hints :(  Many thanks!!

Comment: awesome thanks!! enjoy your time off! :)