# cache them all with hibernate

Tags: hibernate, c3p0, hibernate-entitymanager

I'm using `hibernate-entitymanager` with `c3p0`. My app does not create any "dynamic" queries using `createQuery(...)` nor `createNativeQuery(...)` etc: only "named queries" and automatically generated queries from entity classes. Assuming that I want to cache **all** prepared statements that hibernate may generate, is the formula
`4*numberOfEntityClasses + numberOFNamedQueriesInMyCode` for `maxStatementsPerConnection` correct? (my guess for `4` comes from 1 for each `insert`, `update`, `delete` and `select`).
...or maybe it gets more complicated in case of a complex relation graph between my entities?

Thanks!

**update:** after a moment of consideration, I'm completely almost sure, that I also need to add `1` for each lazily initialized property. So my current guess is
`4*numOfEntities + numOFNamedQueries + numOfLazyProperties`. Anything else that I may be missing? ;-)